# how to access data line by line while its being read in a separate project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have 2 different projects that work with each other. One's a class library and another is a WPF application. So there's a function in the class library which does some data accessing (100000+ rows). My objective is to write these to the WPF app (in a view or table or something) as they are being read. However, my structure doesn't support that. This is why...

```
List<string> _output = new List<string>();
var output = new readBlock<DataRow>(row =>
            {
                _output.Add(row);
            });
```

The above snippet is where I get each row as a string and I add them to a list. This function (in the class library) ultimately returns the list `_output` when its done reading all the rows. This functions prototype looks like this `public static async Task<List<string>> RunAsync`

So the problem here is that, when I want the data, I usually have to wait a minute or so while all the rows are being added to that list.. and only then I can see the data pouring in to my WPF view.

Ideally, every time a new item(row) is added to my list _output, I want to send it to the other project to the WPF view.

```
So when I call it in the WPF app like
TestList = ClassName.RunAsync(params).Result;
// Takes a minute or so to move to next line
foreach (var res in TestList)
  // update view
...
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I would like to keep both projects separate. the WPF App and the data accessing library. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would try async task and await it. So you can continue to interact with the application while your data is loading. Otherwise if you try to update your View 100000+ time. It is going to be unresponsive.

Comment: 1. `yield return`; 2. callback: Have the caller pass in `row => _output.Add(row);` (and btw it's not advisable to prefix local identifiers with an underscore; underscore prefix means "private member" by convention)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I get the following error, `The body of Classname.RunAsync cannot be an iterator block because Task<List<string>> is not an iterator interface type.` I should have included this before properly but this is how I call it `TestList = ClassName.RunAsync(params).Result;` and the function is an aysnc task in the following form `public static async Task<List<string>> RunAsync`

Comment: You want to refresh the UI 100000+  times?  Careful what you ask for.

Comment: @Paparazzi what would be the best way to visualize and store this date as its being read? my plan was to have it on the wpf app and after the read is done, the user can look at the some of the numbers and then export it to excel or csv or something

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you should read data in another thread and invoke to wpf window to update UI while reading, or pass a delegate to your class library and callback while reading lines